# LinkButton permanent underline

Tags: asp.net, controls

I'm using an asp:LinkButton. The text underlines upon hovering over it. However I want it to always have an underline. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting LinkButton.CssClass to "underlinedLinkButton", then add this to your CSS file.

.underlinedLinkButton
{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

Comment: i'd make the selector `a.underlined` (just to be safe)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by setting the `Font-Underline="True"` attribute like so:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="_MyLinkButton" Font-Underline="True" 
    Text="X" OnClick="MyLBClick" />
```